# Perl package error handling question

Tags: perl, exception, try-catch, package

I have a package called "SamplePkg". I have another script that uses SamplePkg, creates an object and calls a method.

```
package SamplePkg;
use strict;
use DBI;
use Try::Tiny;
```

my $dbh = DBI_>connect(..., { RaiseError => 1 });

sub new { 
   my $self = {};
   $self->{CODE} = 0;
   bless($self);
   return $self;
}

sub do_something {
  my $self = shift;
  try { 
     my $query = "select myvalue from mytable";
     $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
     $sth->execute();
  } catch { $self->{CODE} = 100; return; }

$self->{CODE} = 50;
}

The other script

```
use SamplePkg;
```

my $object = SamplePkg->new();
$object->do_something();

print "Code is: $object->{CODE}\n";

Questions:

- For some reason, the try block doesn't catch the DB error (myvalue is not a valid column name)
- The "return" in the catch block does not return to the calling script
- The output gives the error code as 50

Answer (score 1):

```
try { ... } catch { ... };
```

is really

```
try(sub { ... }, catch(sub { ... }));
```

Returning from the sub that's called when an exception is caught returns from that sub, not from the sub in which `try` is located.

You could use

```
try {
   my $query = "select myvalue from mytable";
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
   $sth->execute();
   $self->{CODE} = 50;
} catch {
   $self->{CODE} = 100;
};
```

Or maybe you need something more like

```
my $success = try {
   my $query = "select myvalue from mytable";
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
   $sth->execute();
   return 1;
} catch {
   return 0;
};

... do stuff ...

$self->{CODE} = $succes ? 50 : 100;
```